# How do I run "drush sql-query"?

Tags: drush

I am using Drush 6.0 for my Drupal 7.x site. When I run
`drush sqlq "select * from users where uid=1"`, it always shows the following error:

> 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external  command, operable program or batch file

Why does it happen? How can I avoid it?

Comment: What system are you executing this on?

Comment: I am using it on my local machine (windows 7)

Comment: You will need MySQL command line tools installed locally. This is definitely not bundled with Windows.